# Array not updating in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am working with vuejs + firestore on a project. When i tried to create a new data, i sent an array along with it to firestore. That array is not updated in firestore but it works after i click the button twice. But at the very first time, the array is updated and showed the data in the console. Anyone tell me what's going on?

```
data(){
     return {
       assigning:null,
            subject:null,
            name:null,
            date:null,
            students:[],
            i:0
        }
    },
    methods:{
        add:function(){
            db.collection('students').get().then(doc => {
                console.log(doc.size)
                doc.forEach(r => {
                    this.students.push({name:r.data().Name,stat:false,i:this.i})
                    this.i=this.i+1
                })
                console.log(this.students)
                
            })
        
            db.collection('tests').add({
                type: this.assigning,
                Sub: this.subject,
                Name:this.name,
                Due:this.date,
                status:this.students
            }).then(docref => {
                console.log(this.students)
                console.log(docref)
                // this.$router.push('/')
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                        
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had same kind of issue back then. All I did was instead of directly pushing on cloud array, I copied cloud array to local array then pushed in the local array then replace the cloud array with local array. Although I think there has to be some better method.

Comment: thanks bruh!! I'll try that .

Comment: Did it work? Or not

Comment: I was gonna try that. But i tried a simple method. I put the getting part in the **beforeMount** section and it worked. So I didn't try your idea. sorry bro:(

Comment: Ahh ok np as I said there has to be a better method.